# System sms tools crash after receiving a sms

Tags: android, sms, nullpointerexception

Something strange happens when i receive a sms. When i receive a sms, the system sms tool just CRASH.

here is the log:

```
08-07 11:05:00.750: ERROR/JavaBinder(1369): !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
08-07 11:05:02.080: ERROR/wifi(1369): [android_net_wifi_getRssiHelper] rssi -41
08-07 11:05:02.450: ERROR/[gsm/SmsMessage](1574): SMS PDU parsing failed: 
08-07 11:05:02.450: ERROR/[gsm/SmsMessage](1574): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-07 11:05:02.450: ERROR/[gsm/SmsMessage](1574):     at com.android.internal.telephony.gsm.SmsMessage$PduParser.getByte(SmsMessage.java:911)
08-07 11:05:02.450: ERROR/[gsm/SmsMessage](1574):     at com.android.internal.telephony.gsm.SmsMessage$PduParser.getSCAddress(SmsMessage.java:886)
08-07 11:05:02.450: ERROR/[gsm/SmsMessage](1574):     at com.android.internal.telephony.gsm.SmsMessage.parsePdu(SmsMessage.java:1733)
08-07 11:05:02.450: ERROR/[gsm/SmsMessage](1574):     at com.android.internal.telephony.gsm.SmsMessage.createFromPdu(SmsMessage.java:184)
08-07 11:05:02.450: ERROR/[gsm/SmsMessage](1574):     at android.telephony.SmsMessage.createFromPdu(SmsMessage.java:289)
08-07 11:05:02.450: ERROR/[gsm/SmsMessage](1574):     at android.provider.Telephony$Sms$Intents.getMessagesFromIntent(Telephony.java:765)
08-07 11:05:02.450: ERROR/[gsm/SmsMessage](1574):     at com.android.mms.transaction.SmsReceiverService.handleSmsReceived(SmsReceiverService.java:645)
08-07 11:05:02.450: ERROR/[gsm/SmsMessage](1574):     at com.android.mms.transaction.SmsReceiverService.access$100(SmsReceiverService.java:99)
08-07 11:05:02.450: ERROR/[gsm/SmsMessage](1574):     at com.android.mms.transaction.SmsReceiverService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(SmsReceiverService.java:425)
08-07 11:05:02.450: ERROR/[gsm/SmsMessage](1574):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-07 11:05:02.450: ERROR/[gsm/SmsMessage](1574):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-07 11:05:02.450: ERROR/[gsm/SmsMessage](1574):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
08-07 11:05:02.460: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1574): FATAL EXCEPTION: SmsReceiverService
08-07 11:05:02.460: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1574): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-07 11:05:02.460: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1574):     at android.telephony.SmsMessage.getProtocolIdentifier(SmsMessage.java:1077)
08-07 11:05:02.460: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1574):     at com.android.mms.transaction.SmsReceiverService.insertMessage(SmsReceiverService.java:1691)
08-07 11:05:02.460: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1574):     at com.android.mms.transaction.SmsReceiverService.handleSmsReceived(SmsReceiverService.java:647)
08-07 11:05:02.460: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1574):     at com.android.mms.transaction.SmsReceiverService.access$100(SmsReceiverService.java:99)
08-07 11:05:02.460: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1574):     at com.android.mms.transaction.SmsReceiverService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(SmsReceiverService.java:425)
08-07 11:05:02.460: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1574):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-07 11:05:02.460: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1574):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-07 11:05:02.460: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1574):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
08-07 11:05:05.090: ERROR/wifi(1369): [android_net_wifi_getRssiHelper] rssi -42
08-07 11:05:08.110: ERROR/wifi(1369): [android_net_wifi_getRssiHelper] rssi -44
```

Comment: This might belong better on http://android.stackexchange.com/ since it doesn't directly relate to programming

Answer (score 0):

**juss go to your settings-->applications-->manage applications** then in that go to "All" tab from that select  "Messaging"  now click "Clear data" Button. it might solve your problem